# is an entity stores the first parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does an entity only stores the first parent? or all parents on its own  key.

And how many child can be create.

I want to learn if an entity only saves its parent or the all top parents on KEY.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entity key encode the entity kind, name or id of the entity, and all the entity ancestor keys.

Example `for a -> b -> c (with -> = parent_of)`:

```
>>> a = Foo(id="a").put()
>>> b = Foo(id="b", parent=a).put()
>>> c = Foo(id="c", parent=b).put()
>>> c
Key('Foo', 'a', 'Foo', 'b', 'Foo', 'c')
```

See [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-entitiestable) for more explanation on how entity are stored.

Comment: so if i create 100 of child of child entity the last child store all 100 parents key in its own key?

Comment: a chain of 100 parent-child, or a child with 100 childs?

Comment: a chain of 100 parent-child. a->b->c->d->e

a parent b
b parent c
c parent d
d parent e........ unlimited chains or hundreds of chains